# XML auto generated primary key is not unique with each file

Tags: xml, loops, ssis, primary-key

I am developing a SSIS package (2008 R2) that needs to read multiple xml files. The data gets imported to the database and after data manipulation, pertinent information is output to one XML file.

The steps followed do far:
Loop through XMl files in a ‘ For each loop container’ .
The XML source within the DFT imports each file into 10 tables based on the definition. From there pertinent data is extracted into one staging table.

The process automatically generates an ID field called ‘OrderId’ which makes sense for linking purposes.
However the same Id is being repeated when the next file is being imported. So if I have looped through 10 files, the database shows all 10 of them with the same OrderId.

Ideally I would also like to store each file name during the import process.

Can someone please point me in the right direction (with detailed steps if possible) so that the OrderId is unique with each file.

I thank you so much…..

SD